# Subclipse "remember my descision"

Tags: svn, subclipse

I just used subclipse to show differences in a workspace and accidently clicked "remember my decision" to NOT show the SVN perspective.  How do I change it so that when I click "sync with repo" in subclipse it defaults to the SVN perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed

Window -> Preferences -> Team -> "Open the associated perspective when a synchronize operation completes", change this to "Always".